# Change placeholder text when previous option field changes (PHP / HTML)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 1 dropdown box with different options in it.

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<input placeholder="TEST">
```

I want the placeholder of my input field to change when it's on option 1 or 2

```
Like this:

when dropdown is 1 i want the placeholder of the input field to be A
when dropdown is 2 i want the placeholder of the input field to be B
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @therealbischero Never used it but if i have to use it for that sure.

Comment: "the placeholder of my input field" - where is this ominous input field? Why do you not include it in your markup, so we don't have to invent our own test case?

Comment: @Connum sorry added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add the overhead of jQuery just for this - so, here's a plain JS solution:

```js
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('myInput').setAttribute('placeholder', this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-placeholder'));
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option data-placeholder="A">Option 1</option>
    <option data-placeholder="B">Option 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="default placeholder" />
```

Comment: Sorry i'm totally new to jquery where do i put the jquery code?

Comment: As I explicitely said, this does not use jQuery at all. ;-) So you just put it between `<script></script>` tags after your select/input markup.

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery, you could use this way to achieve what you want. Let me know if you want me to explain it

```js
$('.placeholder-changer').click(function () {
 $('#input-id').attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="placeholder-changer" data-placeholder="placeholder 1">First Option</li>
  <li class="placeholder-changer" data-placeholder="placeholder 2">Second Option</li>
</ul>

<input id="input-id" />
```

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question with a dropdown list i meant somthing like this <select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option></select> will this also work with this?